# Tort vs tord to mean wrong

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, orthographe

I asked someone *Est-ce que j'ai tort?*, and the response was, "Oui, tu as tord."

I thought maybe it was a spelling mistake, but he said that there are two ways of writing it. I can't seem to find anything in English explaining the difference between the two. Is there a difference, or are the two interchangeable?

I found this: http://www.ladictee.fr/grammaire/truc_astuce_grammaire/tort_ou_tord.html but I don't know enough French to know what it means, and Google's auto-translate isn't very helpful.

Comment: Was this written or spoken? Perhaps you may have just heard wrong; otherwise *tort* is the correct spelling for *wrong*.

Comment: @MasonH.Hatfield It was written, which is why I confirmed with him that it wasn't a spelling error. It's odd because he is French.

Comment: That's extremely odd... Especially since he is allegedly French. But many English speakers don't know how to spell things; perhaps that's the case.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*TORT* means *wrong*. It's used with *avoir* in french, and *be* in english

> Parfois, on voudrait *avoir* **tort**.
>
> Sometimes, you just want to *be* **wrong**.

*TORD* means *bend*  (verb **TORDRE** in conjugated form)

> Il peut **tordre** une barre de fer de ses mains.
>
> He can **bend** an iron rod with his hands.

So in your example :

" *Est-ce que j'ai tort ?* " is right but " *Oui, tu as tort* " is the right answer. Your friend is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There was some early overlapping use as a feminine adjective mentioned in *Dictionnaires d'autrefois* ([jambe/bouche/gueule **torte** = jambe/bouche/gueule **tordue**](http://portail.atilf.fr/cgi-bin/dico1look.pl?strippedhw=tors)), but the only **vaguely** “logical” modern connection that I can find between the notions of “tort” and “tord[…]” is in the French-Canadian expression ...
 “se mettre les doigts dans le **tord**eur” ...
 which, according to Pierre DesRuisseaux in *Dictionnaire des expressions québécoise* (I have a copy, but can’t find an online version), means “to adopt an **untenable** [=wrong?] position or point of view” (literally “to put one’s own fingers in/through the wringer”).

However, in spite of this early adjectival connection and my lame attempt to concoct a modern one, I agree with @Chris’ answer that your correspondent is simply wrong and I think you could respond by telling them that if they’re claiming that “tort” and “tord” are interchangeable as two officially recognized spellings of the same word, then they’re perhaps not just mangling their own fingers but the French language as well!

Comment: Hahaha, thanks for that interesting point of view. :)